# How to activate vim-snippets for UltiSnips and Pathogen?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I've installed the UltiSnips and vim-snippets plugins. In order for the snippets to work, I need to activate `vim-snippets` for UltiSnips in my `.vimrc` file.

Vundle version for snipmate looks like this:

> ActivateAddons vim-snippets snipmate

I need to do the same, but for Pathogen and UltiSnips instead of snipmate.

How can I do it?

**Update 1:** My current `.vimrc` (UltiSnips doesn't work).

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
syntax on
execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

I'm using Windows 10 (Russian locale, German keyboard layout).

**Update 2:** With this `.vimrc` file, snippet expansion works in gVim, but not in Vim.

```
set nocompatible
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
syntax on
execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = $HOME.'/vimfiles/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips'
```

Comment: You don't, Pathogen doesn't need explicit activations.  What you need to do is read `UltiSnips` docs and _configure_ it (mainly set `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir`) and the triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to do that for Pathogen + UltiSnips + vim-snippets.
I have such setup and only thing in my vimrc is `let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-j>"`. Both plugins are in `~/.vim/bundle`.

Comment: Does `<c-j>` mean that I have to press Ctrl-j to expand a snippet?

Comment: Yes, I think it was in conflict in my setup with other plugin. From the doc `The variables with their default values are: >
   g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger               <tab>`, so it defaults to `<tab>`

Comment: Thanks. Do you see any errors im my `.vimrc` file (see update 1 above) ?

Comment: Do you have Python installed? Read the `requriments` from the docs. Does your Vim supports Python?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: My last idea is to set `set nocompatible` in vimrc